# Person present at the right time and at the right place

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe "a person present in the right place at the right time"?

Comment: looking for "lucky" ?

Comment: More context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **punctual** and its synonyms like **on time** and **on-the-dot**?

- **Punctual**: arriving, happening, or being done at exactly the time that has been arranged

> *She’s always very *punctual* for appointments.*

This is the closest word I can think of, though some other words like omnipresent might help you!

Comment: "Present at right time at right place" could also not imply something arranged.  For example, I could pass in two different places right in time to help somebody, and I would be said to be "on the right place at the right time"; it doesn't mean I planned to be in both the places to help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

**serendipitous?**

> serendipity (noun): the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way: *a fortunate stroke of serendipity | a series of small serendipities.*

<sub>*New Oxford American Dictionary*</sub>

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but isn't *serendipitous* usually applied to the occurrence rather than the person?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a phrase rather than a single word, the phrase *[Johnny on the spot](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/johnny%20on%20the%20spot.html)* has the appropriate meaning: "Someone ready and available at the time needed."  Also see [worldwidewords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-joh3.htm), which quotes from the April 1896 New York Sun and *Oxford English Dictionary* in explaining the origin of the phrase.